# ODBC Bulk Copy C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc, bulk-load

I was using Bulk Copy like this below and it was working fine:

```
using (SqlTransaction bulkCopyTransaction = connector.RawConnection.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy bk = new SqlBulkCopy(connector.RawConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, bulkCopyTransaction))
    {
```

Then I got the very ugly news that I had to revise my system to use ODBC instead of system.sql.data and there is no bulk copy.  This is a huge problem because I rely on bulk copy a lot.  The reason why they need me to use ODBC is because they want to change computers and passwords and servers whenever they like and not have to worry about recompiling and the app.config file cannot have an unencrypted password in it.

So my needs are that I want to take a CSV file - just as it is - all the columns in the order they come in and put them in an SQL file.  The files can be very big (i.e. 1 GB+)

I have explored using a stored procedure with BCP in it but that requires a password.  I have explored using Bulk Insert and that is a possibility but it will require me to make an XSD file out of every CSV variation (and that is many).  I have looked at the SQL Bulk Copy package (http://www.sqlbulkcopy.org/getting-started/) but that requires column binding as well.

If you have any ideas, input or experience in this, I would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Can you call a SP with a table as a parameter? I.e., does you SQL instance support that? If so, is it an option to supply your data in that manner?

Comment: I can call a SP with a table as a parameter but I can't use bcp in the stored procedure because it requires a password.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but I'm not talking about bcp at all. Just a vanilla SP with a table parameter. This could be used by the ODBC connection without requiring an additional password

Comment: I'm not sure I could send a table as a parameter but I will look.  But, if I could, how would I get the CSV data into the SQL table?

Comment: Or you can always use the `aspnet_regiis.exe` and encrypt those files http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/236688-encryptingdecrypting-your-appconfig-or-webconfig/

Comment: This is a good idea @Hackerman but the Powers That Be already declined any possibility of that.

Comment: Any reason you are unable to do a sql-connection via "Trusted Connection" so no password is ever actually needed to be embedded?  As long as the Windows user has permissions, the connection and bulk upload should be good.

Comment: Maybe user impersonation would be a good workaround?

Comment: Sorry in advance if this seems dumb but it is not my area of expertise.  We don't want to make an SQL user for each Windows user so I don't think we could connected via Trusted Connection.  Please let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: @JacobH - can you elaborate?

Comment: You can encrypt sections of the app.config. I would try to win that fight before switching to odbc.

Comment: Yes but if I encrypt the password section and they want to change the password, it would be too complicated for them to do on their own.  They want to make it so that I have no control over being shut out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fastest way that I found to be able to be able to do this:

```
ObdcCommand cmd = new ObdcCommand("insert into TableName
    select * from OpenRowset
    ('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; 
    ColNameHeader = TRUE; Format = CSVDelimited; ''','select * from" + FileName+"')", connection);
```

Comment: Potentially vulnerable to an injection attack with `" + FileName + "` in there.

Comment: It's true but it's all internal code with WinForms.